# Supply value to Observable

Tags: java, rx-java

I am new to rxjava and I have the following problem:

Objects are irregularly dropped into a FIFO queue by an outside system. I need an Observable which runs every second, takes an item from the queue (if there is one) and emits it to subscribers.

Two problems:

- The queue items are produced while the Observable is alive, it is not possible to provide all items upfront. The queue may run empty, in which case the Observable must standby and not emit anything. (It would be nice if the Observable would jump-start immediately when an item becomes available in the queue after a pause, but then the queue would probably need to be an Observable as well if we don't want to poll more frequently, no idea how.)
- It must be possible for the outside system to complete the Observable. I could set a variable and read it from within the Observable, but I'd like to know if there is a more elegant way to do that.

  ```
  LinkedList<Layer> queue = new LinkedList<Layer>(); // the queue
  boolean stopObservable = false; // the variable to stop the observable

  Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Layer>() {

      @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Layer> subscriber) {
          try {
              if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                  Layer layer = queue.poll();
                  subscriber.onNext(layer);
              } else {
                  if (stopObservable) { subscriber.onCompleted(); }
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              subscriber.onError(e);
          }
      }

  }).somethingThatCreatesTheInterval().subscribeOnEtc.
  ```

For the interval, I cannot use .sample(), because it drops items, and it is important that all items are emitted.

.throttleWithTimeout() looks better, but it also seems to drop items.

rx is very cool, but tough to get into. Any input appreciated.

Comment: So, you don't mind if the queue of input items builds up over time - you just want to emit one every second (or simply skip a "slot" if there is no item available in the input queue)? My first instinct would be to have a look at timer (to provide the "pulse") and map (which does not map anything but simply discards every Long emitted by timer and instead emits the next item from the input queue - or calls onCompleted if the stop variable is set to true). But maybe there's a more elegant alternative...

Comment: Actually I think you might need to use flatMap (instead of map) in the second step - to be able to handle the case that the input queue is empty. So you would either emit an Observable.just() or and Observable.empty().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar when I needed to poll external web services at a regular time interval.

1. For the time interval you could proceed with a [`timer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#timer(long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) ; upon each tick with a granularity of 1s the observable chain will poll and maybe pick one layer, if that layer is null then nothing is emitted

   ```
   Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECOND)
       .flatMap(tick -> Observable.just(queue.poll()).filter(layer -> layer != null))
       .subscribe(layer -> System.out.format("The layer is : %s",  layer));
   ```
2. Now if you want to abort the whole the chain you may add [`takeUntil`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeUntil(rx.Observable)). So when your external system want to stop it will submit something in `stopObservable` which will stop subsequent subscription :

   ```
   // somewhere before
   PublishSubject stopNotifier = PublishSubject.create();

   // somewhere process the queue
   Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECOND)
       .takeUntil(stopNotifier)
       .flatMap(tick -> Observable.just(queue.poll()))
       .subscribe(layer -> System.out.format("The layer is : %s",  layer));

   // when not anymore interested (calling onComplete works too)
   stopNotifier.onNext("cancel everything about the queue");
   ```

I'm writing this response from a tablet so you may assume I may have misspell some words or made naive programming errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should use a `PublishSubject<Layer>` instead of a `LinkedList<Layer>`. Then, the outside system can provide new items by calling `publishSubject.onNext`, and since `PublishSubject` is a subclass of `Observable`, your system can treat it as an Observable, and, depending on what semantics with regard to timing you want, apply one of these operators to it:

- `sample`
- `debounce`
- `throttleFirst`/`throttleLast`/`throttleWithTimeout`
- `.zipWith(Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (value, tick) -> value)` (might do a lot of buffering!)
- no timing modification at all (consider this as well)